# Why i am getting Segfault in below program for pointer but not for array?

Tags: c, generic-programming

1.

```
int a=3,*p=&a;
p++;
*p=10;
```

Then it is giving segmentation fault.

2.

```
int a[3]={1,2,3};
a[10]=10;
```

Then it is working properly

Comment: even if its working how you can assign a[10] if you made array of size 3 ?? That's also wrong

Comment: There is no answer to this. The behavior of both your programs is undefined. So, any of them can segfault or not, depending on compiler, architecture, or other factors.

Comment: I know in 1st pointer is trying to modify the address which it not supposed to, so i am getting segmentation fault there,
But in 2nd Example also i am doing the same then why it is working properly?

Comment: @ChiragGangdev It's seems "working properly", but it might segfault as well. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @ChiragGangdev:   Its Undefined behavior. Go to  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 5):

Both code snippets exhibit [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In both the code snippets, you write into an invalid memory location invoking [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen when you do it. It needn't necessarily segfault or crash. It might work one time, but fail when you do it the next time.

Answer (score 2):

Both the code snippets can result in undefined behavior.

For the first one,

```
int a=3,*p=&a;
p++;
*p=10;
```

You have allocated memory for int a, assume its 4 bytes. then 'p' points to starting address of 'a'. When you do 'p++', since 'p' is of type int*, it increments by size of int. '*p' points to the location (address of a + size of int), which is not allocated. Hence it segmentation faults.

Assuming size of int is 4, your allocation almost looks like this (Haven't considered endianess here).

```
| 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x03 | <Not allocated> | <Not allocated>
```

When you did p++, p points to the first  byte.

In second case, you are just lucky enough that it didn't give seg fault. You have allocated only (3 * size of int) bytes of memory and trying to access a[10], which is not allocated. It might give you a segmentation fault or will return you any garbage value.